# Comparing two arrays of nested objects and return new array of objects if compared values are not the same in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter

I have been having trouble trying to figure out how to get this to work. I have two arrays of nested objects arr1 and arr2.

```
let arr1 =[{
        id: 1,
        rideS: [
        {
          id: 12,
          station: {
            id: 23,
            street: "ABC"
          }
        }
      ]
},
  {
    id: 2,
        rideS: [
        {
          id: 13,
          station: {
            id: 24,
            street: "MMM"
          }
        }
      ]
  }
 ]
 
let arr2 = [
      {
        id: 1,
        so: {
          id: 33,
          sos: [{
            id: 44,
            station: {
              id: 55,
              street: "ABC"
            }
          },
          {
            id: 74,
            station: {
              id: 11,
              street: "DDD"
            }
          }
            
            ]
        }
      },
        {
        id: 2,
        so: {
          id: 34,
          sos: [{
            id: 45,
            station: {
              id: 56,
              street: "RRR"
            }
          },
            {
            id: 51,
            station: {
              id: 66,
              street: "ZZZ"
            }
          }
            ]
        }
      },
    {
        id: 3,
        so: {
          id: 35,
          sos: [{
            id: 46,
            station: {
              id: 57,
              street: "MMM"
            }
          },
            {
            id: 75,
            station: {
              id: 66,
              street: "VVV"
            }
          }
            
            ]
        }
      }
   ]
```

I need to compare arr2 with arr1 using "street" porperty value of first object array in "sos" and as result i need to return not matched objects

For example if i compare this two arrys as result i expect:

```
let result = [ 
 {
        id: 2,
        so: {
          id: 34,
          sos: [{
            id: 45,
            station: {
              id: 56,
              street: "RRR"
            }
          },
            {
            id: 51,
            station: {
              id: 66,
              street: "ZZZ"
            }
          }
            ]
        }
      }
]
```

and this is what i have tried to do

```
let result = arr2.filter(o1 => o1.so.sos.some(o2 => !arr1.some(a1=> a1.rideS.some(a2 => o2.station.street === a2.station.street))))
```

and as result i get all objects, but i need somthing like this prob:

```
 let result = arr2.filter(o1 => o1.so.sos[0].some(o2 => !arr1.some(a1=> a1.rideS.some(a2 => o2.station.street === a2.station.street))))
```

Comment: are you saying if even one of the street name that is preset in Arr1 is matching Arr2, irrespective of any other property it should be removed?

Comment: Yes sir, if any street name from arr1 have same name as street property in arr2 (but only comparing with first object of array "sos") sould not be returned in results

Answer (score 1):

First we need to take out all the street address in a dictionary named `streetDic` and then check in array two if no value inside `streetDic` is present in its streets.

```js
let arr1 =[{
    id: 1,
    rideS: [
    {
      id: 12,
      station: {
        id: 23,
        street: "ABC"
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
id: 2,
    rideS: [
    {
      id: 13,
      station: {
        id: 24,
        street: "MMM"
      }
    }
  ]
}
]

let arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    so: {
      id: 33,
      sos: [{
        id: 44,
        station: {
          id: 55,
          street: "ABC"
        }
      },
      {
        id: 74,
        station: {
          id: 11,
          street: "DDD"
        }
      }
        
        ]
    }
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    so: {
      id: 34,
      sos: [{
        id: 45,
        station: {
          id: 56,
          street: "RRR"
        }
      },
        {
        id: 51,
        station: {
          id: 66,
          street: "ZZZ"
        }
      }
        ]
    }
  },
{
    id: 3,
    so: {
      id: 35,
      sos: [{
        id: 46,
        station: {
          id: 57,
          street: "MMM"
        }
      },
        {
        id: 75,
        station: {
          id: 66,
          street: "VVV"
        }
      }
        
        ]
    }
  }
]



let streetDic = arr1.reduce((dic, o) => {   o.rideS.forEach(r => dic[r.station.street] = true); return dic; } , {})

let result = arr2.filter(o => !o.so.sos.some(s => streetDic[s.station.street]))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `some` with `every`:

```js
let arr1 = [
  { id: 1, rideS: [{id: 12, station: {id: 23, street: "ABC",},},],},
  { id: 2, rideS: [{id: 13, station: {id: 24, street: "MMM",},},],},
];

let arr2 = [
  {id: 1, so: {id: 33, sos: [{id: 44,station: {id: 55,street: "ABC",},}, {id: 74, station: {id: 11, street: "DDD",},},],},},
  {id: 2, so: {id: 34,sos: [{id: 45, station: {id: 56, street: "RRR",},},{id: 51, station: {id: 66, street: "ZZZ",},},],},},
  {id: 3, so: {id: 35, sos: [{id: 46, station: {id: 57, street: "MMM",},},{id: 75, station: {id: 66, street: "VVV",},},],},},
];
    
let result = arr2.filter(o1 => o1.so.sos.every(o2 => !arr1.some(a1 => a1.rideS.some(a2 => o2.station.street === a2.station.street))))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Don't thank me, it was your code, I just spotted your lapsus :) cheers mate :),